# Open Web Analytics in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

How can I run [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) software through Joomla? Is there any plugin?

For example in order to run piwik through Joomla you can use the plugin named nfrPiwik.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a plugin for neither **Open Web Analytics** nor **Piwik**, the easiest way is to paste the provided tracking code directly into your template's `index.php` file (`ROOT/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/index.php`).

It's usually a Javascript snippet, like the [example located here](http://demo.openwebanalytics.com/jstracker.php). OWA also has a [PHP tracking code](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=PHP_Invocation) that can be used.

I had a quick look at the [nfrPiwik](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/site-management/analytics/nfrpiwik) plugin, and all it does is insert the tracking code you paste into the plugin parameters right before the `</body>` tag of your website. The plugin itself contains no Piwik specific coding, so you can simply use your OWA code (or Google Analytics code - or any other script) in the input box.

Comment: Rather than making changes to `index.php` which can be overwritten by updates, you could add the code to a Custom HTML module and publish this to the "debug" or similar module position which is often included with templates. You may need to install and enable Sourcerer or similar to be able to save the code.

Comment: @NeilRobertson: yes, adding the code to a module is another option. You should add that as an answer, it might benefit other users.